# Should Rails [seed] questions be retagged [seeding]?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

91 questions have [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) and [seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seed), while 64 questions have [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) and [seeding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seeding).

The tag wiki for [seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seed) says

> Seed is a JavaScript interpreter and a library of the GNOME project.

Should the Rails-related questions be retagged from seed to seeding?

Answer (score -1):

In rails context the "seeding" means to run a script that populates a newly created database with data the application requires to run, such as possible user roles etc. The seeding is initiated with command `rake db:seed` so I think the tag could be `db-seed`.